# store ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE duplicate values

Tags: php, mysqli

When I execute a query with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` I want to know which values are duplicates. Is there a function in mysqli that can return the updated duplicate records?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We would need a lot more information to be able to help you, so I'd advise you to read the [help section about asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing your question accordingly.

Comment: I gave you enough information. Just wanted to know the procedure. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such function. Unfortunately, you can't get this information. What you can do is execute another `SELECT` with the same criteria to get the would-be-updated rows separately.